# Loss function for segmentation of a single connected component

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, loss, semantic-segmentation

I am training a model for the segmentation of a medical image.

There is a condition: it needs to cover a single whole region of the image.

However, my model (U-Net) sometimes shows more than one region even though all labels in the dataset contain one region each and one only. We want to train the model and eliminate those small regions without using any post-processing.

Is the idea of giving a penalty for outputting more than one region wrong? I know that the model might be overfitting, but I would like to try to solve this problem with the above ideas.

- Label:

  [image]
- Incorrect output:

  [image]

Settings:

- model: U-Net
- loss: `0.5 * cross-entropy + 0.5 * dice-score`
- additional considerations: data augmentation and early stopping.

Comment: What do you mean by `single connected component in a image` ?

Comment: Thx for your comment. I'll fix the confusing text. 
I meant that there is only one region like that image. [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVqo.png)